# Automatically generate valid json strings in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to dynamically create a json string in python. So far i have this where testcase_ids is a list of unique numbers.

```
    for x in testcase_ids:
        result_details = '{"case_id": ' + str(x) + ',"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"}'
        results.append(result_details)
    result_list = ','.join(results)
    json_string = json.dumps(result_list)
    data = {"results": [ json_string ]}

    print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

However the output of json.dumps one long string..

```
{
    "results": ["\"{\\\"case_id\\\": 76565,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"},
    {\\\"case_id\\\": 76601,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"},
    {\\\"case_id\\\": 76668,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"},
    {\\\"case_id\\\": 76731,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"},
    {\\\"case_id\\\": 76737,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"},
    {\\\"case_id\\\": 23467,\\\"status_id\\\": 1,\\\"version\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"comment\\\":\\\"Test\\\"}\""
    ]
}
```

What i want to get to in the end is this though:

```
data3 = {'results': [{"case_id": 76565,"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"},
                         {"case_id": 76601,"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"},
                         {"case_id": 76668,"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"},
                         {"case_id": 23467,"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"}]},
```

Which looks like this when printed...

```
[
    {
        "results": [
            {
                "case_id": 76565,
                "comment": "Test",
                "status_id": 1,
                "version": "1.0"
            },
            {
                "case_id": 76601,
                "comment": "Test",
                "status_id": 1,
                "version": "1.0"
            },
            {
                "case_id": 76668,
                "comment": "Test",
                "status_id": 1,
                "version": "1.0"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I also tried this, but it was still failing until i added json.loads after the json.dumps. This converted the string into a valid json string. Fixed!

```
    for x in mrc_testcase_ids:
        result_details = {"case_id": str(x),"status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"}
        results.append(result_details)
    json_string = json.dumps([{'results': results}])
    valid_json_string = json.loads(json_string)
    print (json.dumps(valid_json_string, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Don't encode the string manually, that's the whole point of the json dump! Put everything into a dict and then let `json.dumps()` do it for you. Just recreate the exact structure you want to have as an output inside Python, and then dump it. Edit: it's not clear to me whether you actually want the whole thing as a string (which `json.dumps()` will return) or if you just want this nested structure at the end here.

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I'd like it as a string, i just put the nested structure there to make it clearer that my current output does not appear to be a valid json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it will work.

```
for x in testcase_ids:
    result_details = {"case_id": "" + str(x) + "","status_id": 1,"version":"1.0","comment":"Test"}
    results.append(result_details)
json_string = json.dumps(result_list)
```

Comment: With my above amendments the output is now: "[{\"results\": [{\"comment\": \"Test\", \"version\": \"1.0\", \"case_id\": \"76565\", \"status_id\": 1}, {\"comment\": \"Test\", \"version\": \"1.0\", \"case_id\": \"76601\", \"status_id\": 1}, {\"comment\": \"Test\", \"version\": \"1.0\", \"case_id\": \"234673\", \"status_id\": 1}]}]". Which still isn't a valid json string. Its closer though.

Comment: This was close. It also requires json.loads after the json.dumps. valid_json_string = json.loads(json_string)